# ssis substring charindex , split forename and surname

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, derived-column

I have an Excel source in SSIS with a column called `[Name]` which has an entry like `Joe Bloggs`

I want to separate [Name] into [Forename] and [Surname]

How can I make two derived columns please as it does not work as an SQL statement

As normal SQL would be:

```
SUBSTRING([Name], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [Name]) - 1) AS [Forename]

SUBSTRING([Name], CHARINDEX(' ', [Name]) + 1, LEN([Name])) AS [Surname]
```

`CHARINDEX()` does not work in derived columns

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Correct, SSIS is a different product from TSQL so you'll need to use language appropriate syntax.

You'll want to add a derived column component to find the first space. The `FINDSTRING` operator is what you're looking for.  `FINDSTRING([Name]," ",1)` and add that as a new column called SpacePosition

Add a second derived column component after that to allow you to create the forename/surname columns. Syntax here though should match what you've provided

```
SUBSTRING([Name], 1, [SpacePosition] - 1)
RIGHT([Name], [SpacePosition] + 1)
```

The reason I advocate for doing this in two steps that if you're getting incorrect results, then you can at least confirm did SpacePosition yield the expected results. Because you may end up with `Madonna`, `Prince`, or `Lee Harvey Oswald` in your input data.

[Remove Text from a String in SSIS derived column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020866/remove-text-from-a-string-in-ssis-derived-column/33023858#33023858)

Comment: Hi I tried the above with no joy sorry I get error row disposition - please help @billinkc

Comment: Also using substring some of the names have middle names , I just want the first name please x there are names like Joe Fred Bloggs. please help

Comment: So the data is "Joe Fred Bloggs", what goes in First Name and what goes in Last Name?

Comment: Just Fred in Forename and Bloggs in surname...some have entered a odd two middle names in by accident , need to fish them out. please help x

Comment: resolved the error in disposition but cant rid of the middle name x please help

Comment: resolved using something like SUBSTRING(<field>, FINDSTRING(<field>, " ", 2)+1, LEN(<field>)).. thank you team xxx

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TOKEN()` and `TOKENCOUNT()` functions to split the column as follows:

*First name:*

```
TOKEN([Name]," ",1)
```

*Last name:*

```
TOKEN([Name]," ",TOKENCOUNT([Name]," "))
```

In addition, the `FINDSTRING()` function is the alternative of SQL `CHARINDEX()` function in the SSIS expressions. As an example:

```
FINDSTRING([Name], " ", 1)
```

---

**References**

- [TOKEN (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/token-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [TOKENCOUNT (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/tokencount-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [FINDSTRING (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/findstring-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15)