# How to debug derived column

Tags: ssis

I have a package that drops errors on the derived column. The error messages only say "an error occured on the derived column" without telling me the nature, or the operation that it fails to do.

Is there a way to have some kind of verbose mode, or more precision on what dropped the error?

Comment: I can only answer in the generic, but if you provide your expression, sample input data that works and data that doesn't work and the expected outcome for the failing case, we the StackOverflow collective can debug where things have gone awry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. A challenge with the SSIS expression language is that it happens or it doesn't. There's no facility to step through the intermediate values.

I did a lot of SSIS development in my life and the advice I give everyone is that you should break your expressions down into the smallest operation available and [make use of many steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020866/remove-text-from-a-string-in-ssis-derived-column/33023858#33023858). If you're using SSIS Variables, chain them together so you *can* see what the exact input was before it gave a bad value. In a Data Flow, you'll do a similar process but add multiple Derived Columns to the data flow. The trivial amount of overhead it is going to add to the process is dwarfed by the other operations you'll be performing plus, it's your only lifeline for debugging.